# Visualization with JavaScript of data from a JSON source?

Tags: json, charts, visualization, sparql, rdfa

I would like to use a library like the [Google Visualization API to draw charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/index.html), but taking the data as JSON from an external source. The context is to use [some SPARQL service](http://sparql.org/query.html) to extract the data from a XHTML+RDFa source, as described [here](http://www.pharmash.com/posts/2010-09-27-sparql-to-chart.html). But that latter page has to use a trick, but points out that it would be great that these visualization toolkits can take data input directly from JSON returned by some web page.

Is there a chart visualization library that supports taking the data it visualizes directly from a JSON-returning URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com).  In one of their [examples](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/?example=line-ajax&theme=dark), jQuery.getJSON() is employed to fetch data as JSON.  For external URLs, there may be an issue with the same origin policy, unless the external service has JSONP callbacks.